# remove box on click on infinite scroll page by using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a page with infinite scroll which contain box with delete button inside it.As we scroll page, new box should be generated.
if we click on delete button of any given box,that particular box and button itself should get deleted with alert message.

I have written some code and tried to append the child element to parent element when we scroll and tried to delete child and parent element when click event occurs.
As i am new to javascript, please help me to correct this code or tell me how to approach this problem.
Please provide solution in javascript only(no jquery).

```js
var contain = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('floating-box');
//box scroll event
document.addEventListener('scroll', addbox);
//box delete event
box.addEventListener('click', rmbox);

function addbox(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var newitem = document.getElementById('box');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.className = 'Floating-Box';
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newitem));
  var deletebtn = document.createElement('button');
  deletebtn.className = 'del';
  deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));
  p.appendChild(deleteBtn);
  contain.appendChild(p);
  var contentHeight = contain.offsetHeight;
  var y = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
  if (y >= ContentHeight) {
    contain.appendChild(contain.childNodes(this));
  }

}

function rmbox(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      var p = e.target.parentElement;
      contain.removeChild(p);
    }
  }


}
```

```css
.floating-box>div {
  float: left;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}

.floating-box>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}

.del>div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
  <title>page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What all are the problems that you need resolved here? That the delete button for the boxes may work?

Comment: you can only use each ID once in a page. In this example, you have the ID `box` twice. Also, the ID should be between "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have fixed most of the code. As the changes were many, I am not able to explain all of them at the moment. I will try editing the answer soon. Kindly study the code and see where your mistakes were in the meantime.

```js
var contain = document.getElementById('container');
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('floating-box');
//box scroll event

for(var i=0, l=boxes.length; i<l; i++){
 boxes[i].addEventListener('click', rmbox);
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', addbox);

function addbox(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.className = 'Floating-Box';
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some Text '));
  var deletebtn = document.createElement('button');
  deletebtn.className = 'del';
  deletebtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));
  deletebtn.addEventListener('click', rmbox);
  p.appendChild(deletebtn);
  contain.appendChild(p);
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    contain.appendChild(p);
  }

}

function rmbox(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('del')) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      var p = e.target.parentElement;
      p.parentElement.removeChild(p);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.floating-box>div {
  float: left;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}


.floating-box>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}

.del>div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
  <title>page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
    <p id=box class="floating-box">box
      <button class="del">X</button>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how to append only 20 child node to parent node on scroll instead of this. We can either add for loop to append child node or manage innerheight in such a way that it only show few child node only

Comment: If the number of nodes is known beforehand, you could just decrement a counter each time a child node is added, and once the count reaches 0, the function can just do nothing, or the event handler can be removed altogether.

Comment: no of node can be  found out using "document.getElementById("container").childElementCount;"

Comment: after this we can add for loop to add element to the last node. Now if we again scroll it should append same num of elements if we scroll again.